# Loop a save code that references another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have one worksheet (Sheet1) with 50 different 5 digit number codes, all in A1:A50. i have another worksheet (Sheet2) that has A1 referencing Sheet1-A1's 5 digit number code. My goal is to save Sheet2 as the 5 digit number that was just referenced, then erase A1 of Sheet2 and reference A2 in Sheet1 then do the save process again until i have 50 different worksheet. i have the code for the saving portion, but i cant quite figure out how to loop it for the remaining cell references in Sheet1

```
Dim part1 As String

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Sheet1.xlsx]Tiering'!R1C1"
part1 = Range("BA1").Value


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\Desktop\" & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY") & " " & part1 & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Range("A1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

In summary, this code works, i just need to loop it so that it saves the other 50 codes in Sheet1's range A1:A50

thank you

Answer (score 0):

this should give you an idea

there is no need to place a formula in a cell

```
Sub test()

    Dim part1 As String

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 49

        part1 = Workbooks("Sheet1.xlsx").Sheets("Tiering").Range("a1").Offset(i).Value
        debug.print part1

    Next i

End Sub
```